# C fgets versus fgetc for reading line

Tags: c, io, stdio, fgets, fgetc

I need to read a line of text (terminated by a newline) without making assumptions about the length. So I now face to possibilities:

- Use `fgets` and check each time if the last character is a newline and continuously append to a buffer
- Read each character using `fgetc` and occasionally `realloc` the buffer

Intuition tells me the `fgetc` variant might be slower, but then again I don't see how `fgets` can do it without examining every character (also my intuition isn't always that good). The lines are quite large so the performance is important.

I would like to know the pros and cons of each approach. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using `fgets()` coupled with dynamic memory allocation - or you can investigate the interface to [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) that is in the POSIX 2008 standard and available on more recent Linux machines.  That does the memory allocation stuff for you.  You need to keep tabs on the buffer length as well as its address - so you might even create yourself a structure to handle the information.

Although `fgetc()` also works, it is marginally fiddlier - but only marginally so.  Underneath the covers, it uses the same mechanisms as `fgets()`.  The internals may be able to exploit speedier operation - analogous to `strchr()` - that are not available when you call `fgetc()` directly.

Comment: The one limitation when implementing a `getline` function with `fgets` is that it is impossible to handle null bytes **and** files not ending with a newline character at the same time. If `fgets` encounters an EOF condition and returns without a newline character, you can only assume that the string ends on the first null byte. (In other cases, you can do `strchr(buf, '\n')` to find out where the reading stopped—or if there is no `'\n'`, you need to `realloc`.)

Comment: If the file contains null bytes, it isn't a text file.  (It might be a wide character file, but then you need to use wide character I/O functions to read it.)  And `fgets()` is not designed to handle files that contain null bytes — precisely because it does not give a reliable indication of how many bytes it read.  If your data file contains null bytes, you should (probably) not be using `fgets()` to read it.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline (Return Value section) seems to suggest that it might be a useful thing. That's where I got the idea, although I guess I agree with you. Now that I think about it, maybe that's only mentioned there because it could be useful when using a delimiter other than `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

Does your environment provide the `getline(3)` function? If so, I'd say go for that.

The big advantage I see is that it allocates the buffer itself (if you want), and will `realloc()` the buffer you pass in if it's too small. (So this means you need to pass in something gotten from `malloc()`).

This gets rid of some of the pain of fgets/fgetc, and you can hope that whoever wrote the C library that implements it took care of making it efficient.

Bonus: the man page on Linux has a nice example of how to use it in an efficient manner.

Comment: Unfortunately (I am sorry I did not mention this in the question) I need to use standard stuff :-( The getline functions sure sounds attractive.

Comment: Well, it is standard (for some definition of standard). See [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), aka "IEEE Std 1003.1™-2008" aka "POSIX C 2008". But standard != widespread, unfortunately. I feel your pain. getline is sexy :-)

Comment: `getline()` functionality is good; the name `getline()` is an atrocious intrusion on the user namespace, pre-empting one of the more widely used function names (for example, see K&R 1 and 2) with a wide range of diverse interfaces.  It was an *appalling* decision to use that name; it was an *excellent* decision to provide the functionality.  The only surprising thing is the omission of the ability to handle CRLF line endings; the related `getdelim()` function can handle CR or LF or NUL line endings, but cannot handle CRLF line endings.

Answer (score 2):

If performance matters much to you, you generally want to call `getc` instead of `fgetc`. The standard tries to make it easier to implement `getc` as a macro to avoid function call overhead.

Past that, the main thing to deal with is probably your strategy in allocating the buffer. Most people use fixed increments (e.g., when/if we run out of space, allocate another 128 bytes). I'd advise instead using a constant *factor*, so if you run out of space allocate a buffer that's, say, 1 1/2 times the previous size.

Especially when `getc` is implemented as a macro, the difference between `getc` and `fgets` is usually quite minimal, so you're best off concentrating on other issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set a maximum line length, even a large one, then one `fgets` would do the trick. If not, multiple `fgets` calls will still be faster than multiple `fgetc` calls because the overhead of the latter will be greater.

A better answer, though, is that it's not worth worrying about the performance difference until and unless you have to. If `fgetc` is fast enough, what does it matter?

Comment: Also note that `getc` is usually implemented as a macro and is therefore faster than `fgetc`, and should be used as long as you are careful (argument can't be an expression).

Answer (score 0):

I would allocate a large buffer and then use fgets, checking, reallocing and repeating if you haven't read to the end of the line.

Each time you read (either via fgetc or fgets) you are making a system call which takes time, you want to minimize the number of times that happens, so calling fgets fewer times and iterating in memory is faster.

If you are reading from a file, `mmap()`ing in the file is another option.

Comment: I have to contradict you on the system call part: the stdio library does buffering so I don't think every function call will be translated into a system call. I may be wrong

Comment: this is true, but with fgets he will have finer grained control. if he has some idea of how long the lines are on average he can optimize the buffer lengths, rather than fgetc which will buffer but be completely agnostic about ideal buffer lengths.