# getc evaluates stream more than once

Tags: c

While reading the `getc` man page, I came across:

> **may be** implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.

So, `getc` might be implemented as a function as well - what exactly means by **evaluates stream more than once**?

Comment: It means that since `getc` is a macro, it's `stream` parameter may be expanded multiple times wherever it's used inside the macro. If you don't want this behavior, use `fgetc`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Can you provide any reference to look at `getc`'s macro implementation?

Comment: You could check the standard library's source code on your own system and see `getc`'s implementation. Though it may not be implemented as a macro. It's allowed to be, but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a function:

```
FILE *getstream(void);
```

And a code:

```
int c = getc(getstream());
```

In case `getc` is a function, `getstream` will be called only once, its result will be stored in a temporary variable/register and passed to `getc`.

In case `getc` is a macro, let say something like:

```
#define getc(s)  ((s) == NULL) ? -1 :_getc(s))
```

it will get expanded into:

```
int c = (((getstream()) == NULL) ? -1 :_getc(getstream()));
```

That is it will call `getstream()` *twice*. In case `getstream` has some side effects (using IO, modifying some global state), the flow of the program will be different between the two cases and one must be aware of this.

Comment: However I suppose it is rather uncommon to call `getc`  with a parameter whose multiple evaluation may cause problems.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'd say it should not be done at all, exactly for this reason :)

Comment: Exactly, otherwise calling `getc(getstream())` in a loop may also trigger problems.

Comment: @EugeneSh. isn't this entire case valid for any macro vs unction situation?

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus Yes, of course. When dealing with macros one should be fully aware of possible pitfalls (and there is a bunch)

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus: Yes, but the point of warning you about it in the documentation for `getc` is that people may think of the standard library facilities as functions and so forget about the possibility they are macros that may evaluate their arguments multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

This means that the expression passed to `getc` as an argument could be evaluated multiple times.  So if this expression contains an assignment, increment/decrement, or function call, it will happen more than once.

For example, given this macro:

```
#define PRINT_INT(x) printf("%d (%x)\n", (x), (x))
```

This code:

```
int x = 3;
PRINT_INT(++x);
```

Will expand to:

```
int x = 3;
printf("%d (%x)\n", (++x), (++x))
```

This would cause `x` to get incremented more than once without a sequence point and trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The man page is saying that `getc` may be doing something similar, so don't pass anything to it that could have a side effect.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that *if* you were to write something like

```
int c = getc(fp[i++]);
```

you would potentially run into big trouble, because the `getc` macro might evaluate its argument `fp[i++]` twice, meaning not only that `i` would potentially get bumped by 2, but also because (in the absence of sequence points) you'd descend all the way into formally undefined behavior.

But if you never call `getc` on an argument with a side effect, it's perfectly safe.

For some reason, I see people calling `fgetc` more and more often these days.  Presumably they're being taught this because it's "safer", although to my mind, it's a pretty unnecessary concern in the grand scheme of things.

See also [getc() vs fgetc() - What are the major differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480982/getc-vs-fgetc-what-are-the-major-differences).

Answer (score 1):

You must not suppose that getc's argument is evaluated conforming to a function-call discipline (call-by-value in this case).

This comes from the paragraph "*7.19.7.5 The getc function*" the [ISO 9899](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) that defines the C language:

> The getc function is equivalent to fgetc, except that if it is
> implemented as a macro, it may  evaluate stream more  than  once,  so
> the  argument  should  never be an expression with side effects

The definitions of the libc functions that you find in the linux man pages come from a combination of sources that vary between the ISO9899, POSIX, etc (see the `CONFORMING TO` paragraphs from each manual to see the origin of the definitions).